# How to return 5 topmost values from vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, topmost

I have a vector and I'm able to return highest and lowest value, but how to return 5 topmost values? Is there a simple one-line solution for this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
> a <- c(1:100)
> tail(sort(a),5)
[1]  96  97  98  99 100
```

Comment: Or `head(sort(a, decreasing=TRUE), 5)`

Comment: tail is slightly faster than head and decreasing = TRUE

> x <- rnorm(50000000)
> system.time(tail(sort(x), 5))
   user  system elapsed 
  22.64    0.25   22.95 
> system.time(head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE), 5))
   user  system elapsed 
  23.26    0.20   23.51

Comment: @Thierry You should run this more then once and take average time. Cause I think there is no difference (statistically speaking), based on my simulations.

Comment: I get on average 2% faster times for user.self and elapse. The gain on sys.self is 8%. But the relevance on the gain depends on the application.

Comment: Using sort(x, method='quick') is significantly faster, but David's solution below using the partial argument is even faster.

Answer (score 25):

```
x[order(x)[1:5]]
```

Comment: should be `x[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5]]` but the accepted answer is good

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `head( X, 5)` where `X` is your sorted vector.

Answer (score 3):

```
tail(sort.int(x, partial=length(x) - 4), 5)
```

Using sort.int with partial has the advantage of being (potentially) faster by (potentially) not doing a full sort. But in reality, my implementation appears a little slower. Maybe this is because with parameter partial != NULL, shell sort is used rather than quick sort?

```
> x <- 1:1e6
> system.time(replicate(100, tail(sort.int(x, partial=length(x) - 4), 5)))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.782   0.846   5.668
> system.time(replicate(100, tail(sort(x), 5)))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.643   0.879   4.854
```

Comment: If you instead use x<-runif(1e6) you'd see the benefit. Note that those 5 values you get back would indeed be the highest 5, but not necessarily in a sorted order.