# how to use graph.coreness to find the largest k-core the vertex belongs to

Tags: r, graph

I found the documentation [here](http://igraph.org/r/doc/graph.kcores.html) on how to use `graph.coreness`.

Unfortunately I get back a list of numbers which was about 27000 entries long.

My purpose is to simply figure out how to find out the largest k-core the entries belong to.

How do I do that?

Comment: Posting this as a comment, as I am not really sure whether this is what you need, but I guess `which.max(table(graph.coreness(g)))` should do the trick. Right?

Comment: Tried it. this gives me the largest vertex, but not the largest k-core the vertices belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out using this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3692710/80353

Basically I do this.

```
cores = graph.coreness(as.undirected(g))
head(sort(cores, decreasing=TRUE), 3)
```

This will give me the 3 highest k-core values in the vector.

Answer (score 5):

Supposing to have this graph :

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.empty(n=7,directed=FALSE)
g <- add.edges(g, c(1,2,1,3,1,4,3,5,3,4,4,5,2,7,2,6))
g <- set.vertex.attribute(g, name='vert.names',index=V(g),value=LETTERS[V(g)])
```

[image: graph]

You can get the k-core subgraph in this way :

```
coreness <- graph.coreness(g) 
maxCoreness <- max(coreness)
# if you just need to know the vertices and not to build the subgraph 
# you can use this variable
verticesHavingMaxCoreness <- which(coreness == maxCoreness) 
kcore <- induced.subgraph(graph=g,vids=verticesHavingMaxCoreness)

plot(kcore, 
     vertex.label=get.vertex.attribute(kcore,name='vert.names',index=V(kcore)))
```

[image: k-core subgraph]

Comment: Improved example with vertices labeling.

Comment: Woo! Awesome answer!~ Picture me like-y