# R: returning the 5 rows with the highest values

Tags: r

Sample data

```
mysample <- data.frame(ID = 1:100, kWh = rnorm(100))
```

I'm trying to automate the process of returning the rows in a data frame that contain the 5 highest values in a certain column. In the sample data, the 5 highest values in the "kWh" column can be found using the code:

```
(tail(sort(mysample$kWh), 5))
```

which in my case returns:

```
[1] 1.477391 1.765312 1.778396 2.686136 2.710494
```

I would like to create a table that contains rows that contain these numbers in column 2.
I am attempting to use this code:

```
mysample[mysample$kWh == (tail(sort(mysample$kWh), 5)),]
```

This returns:

```
   ID      kWh  
87 87 1.765312
```

I would like it to return the r rows that contain the figures above in the "kWh" column. I'm sure I've missed something basic but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `rank`

```
mysample$Rank <- rank(-mysample$kWh)
head(mysample[order(mysample$Rank),],5)
```

if we don't need to create column, directly use `order` (as @Jaap mentioned in three alternative methods)

```
#order descending and get the first 5 rows
head(mysample[order(-mysample$kWh),],5)
#order ascending and get the last 5 rows
tail(mysample[order(mysample$kWh),],5) 
#or just use sequence as index to get the rows.
mysample[order(-mysample$kWh),][1:5]
```

Comment: why not just `head(mysample[order(-mysample$kWh),],5)`?

Comment: @Jaap Yes, it is possible, but I thought I read something like to create a new column or so.

Comment: @Jaap I used tail instead of head after reading this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692563/how-to-return-5-topmost-values-from-vector-in-r

Comment: I've tested akrun's answer and Jaap's, both work with my sample data. I like Jaap's because it's neater and doesn't add a column to the data. However, it doesn't work with my actual data, so I'm going to have to do some more investigating. The question as asked was answered, many thanks.

Comment: @Volcanic  i added column as i thought you may need it

Comment: @akrun maybe you can add these alternatives as well: `tail(mysample[order(mysample$kWh),],5)` & `mysample[order(-mysample$kWh),][1:5]`

Comment: simple enough for my needs: `mysample[mysample$Rank<6,]`  @akrun, the rank column was needed after all. This works with my real data. Very happy.